# Slow Query in Big Tables by a field has INDEX

Tags: mysql, query

i don't understand the problem in this query, when I make a query with a condition of category_id = 'XX' the query take MINUTES to execute, but the same query without filter by category_id take 0.09 seconds, and the category_id is an int(11) Unsigned INDEX..

Here is my tables:

http://www.youcial.es/tableproblems/table_business.htm

http://www.youcial.es/tableproblems/table_products.htm

EXPLAINS:

http://www.youcial.es/tableproblems/explain_fast.htm

http://www.youcial.es/tableproblems/explain_slow.htm

The ONLY difference is the filter by category_id.. I don't find the slow performance problem filtering by this field.. What may be the possible problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use LIMIT 0,30
Your request without category_id = 'XX' find the first 30 values very fast.
Your request with category_id = 'XX' have to dig into your tables to find 30 rows (probably because you don't have a lot of 'xx').

If you remove LIMIT 0,30 your 2 requests will have about the same run lenght.